# Exportando dados em json ou txt, no python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Estou precisando da ajuda para aprender como exportar dados, apartir de um objeto. A principio preciso exportar no tipo "txt" e/ou "json", porém não consegui ter êxito em nenhum dos dois.

O código:

```
#coding = utf-8
import json

.
.
.
 def arquivo(lista_nomes):
     print(json.dumps(lista_nomes))


 def txt(lista_nomes):
     arq = open('listaNomes.txt', 'w')
     arq.write(for i in lista_nomes:)
     arq.close()

for lista_nome in lista:
    txt(lista_nomes)
    arquivo(lista_nomes)
.
.
.
```

Tentando exportar com a função "txt", só consigo um linha com apenas um nome, e com uso do json_dumps não gero nenhuma saída(não entendi bem como usar a lib 'json' do python, pensei que era para exportar dados.)

Também pergunto como devo fazer para saída ser em charset UTF-8? A saída, quando imprimo o resultado no compilador python, vem com caracteres não reconhecidos, logo não entendi o porque já que o codigo está 'setado' em utf-8.

Fico no aguardo pessoal, para me ajudarem na solução do problema.

Comment: Como está a estrutura desse teu .txt? Um nome por linha? E como e qual ordem as funções estão sendo chamadas no teu arquivo principal..

Comment: @Marlysson, sim o texto vem um [" nome", "linformações"]. Quanto as funções acredito que não importe, porém a chamada delas é a mesma que foi postada acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá, uma coisa de cada vez.

O módulo `json` tem duas funções parecidas mas diferentes: `dump`, que aceita o objeto a ser convertido *e um arquivo*, e `dumps`, que aceita *só o objeto e retorna uma string*.

Pra escrever um arquivo json, portanto, é mais interessante usar o `dump`:

```
import json

def escrever_json(lista):
    with open('meu_arquivo.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(lista, f)

def carregar_json(arquivo):
    with open('meu_arquivo.json', 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)

minha_lista = ['João', 'Maria', 'José']
escrever_json(minha_lista)

print(carregar_json('meu_arquivo.json'))  # ['João', 'Maria', 'José']
```

Pra texto, usamos `write` pra escrever. Se não incluirmos o caractere de nova linha, todos os nomes serão gravados sem espaço, então temos que fazer isso:

```
def escrever_txt(lista):
    with open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for nome in lista:
            f.write(nome + '\n')

def carregar_txt():
    with open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return f.readlines()

minha_lista = ['João', 'Maria', 'José']
escrever_txt(minha_lista)

print(carregar_txt())  # ['João\n', 'Maria\n', 'José\n']
```

Se quisermos que os nomes venham de volta sem o caractere de linha nova, podemos modificar um pouco a função:

```
def carregar_txt():
    with open('meu_arquivo.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return [nome.strip() for nome in f.readlines()]
```

Comment: Opa pedro, ainda sim com sua solução não estou conseguindo formar arquivos txt e json com linhas subsequentes, como em um texto ou pagina de livro. Só consigo gerar a primeira linha e salva-la. Isso é parte de um projeto, logo preciso salvar objeto que recebo exportando para um "arquivo.txt" e/ou "arquivo.json".